# Какой плагин Parallax используется?

Tags: parallax

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой плагин Parallax применен на [этом](http://boy-coy.com/) сайте? Я делаю лендинг, где нужно применить такой же **плавный** эффект при прокрутке. Целый день ищу и не могу найти подобный плагин, везде попадаются плагины без плавного движения элементов. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Изучайте http://boy-coy.com/js/j.js